# Show node body fields for entity reference checkboxes widget?

Tags: 7, entities

I need to show the body field of the nodes next to their checkboxes in an entity reference field widget (default is just their node titles). Is there a way to do that without writing a new widget?

Comment: I just did this by hook_form_alter until I figure out a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Entity Reference View Widget](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget).

> This module provides an advanced Entity Reference widget that uses a
>   view for selecting items. The view can be paginated and have exposed
>   filters. It degrades, so it can be used even if Javascript is disabled